# How to join a spark dataframe twice with different id type

Tags: apache-spark, join, pyspark

I have a `spark.DataFrame` called `events` and I want to join with another `spark.DataFrame` called `users`. Therefore the User can ben identified on `events` dataframe with two different types of Id.
The schema of dataframes can be seen below:
Events:

| Id | IdType | Name | Date | EventType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | UserId | Daniel | 2022-01-15 | purchase |
| 350 | UserId | Jack | 2022-01-16 | purchase |
| 3247623322 | UserCel | Michelle | 2022-01-10 | claim |

Users:

| Id | Name | Cel |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | Daniel | 5511737379 |
| 350 | Jack | 3247623817 |
| 380 | Michelle | 3247623322 |

What I want to do is to `left join` the `events` dataframe twice in order to extract all the events despite the `IdType` used on `events` dataframe

The final dataframe I want must be as follows:

| Id | Name | Cel | Date | EventType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 324 | Daniel | 5511737379 | 2022-01-15 | Purchase |
| 350 | Jack | 3247623817 | 2022-01-16 | Purchase |
| 380 | Michelle | 3247623322 | 2022-01-10 | Claim |

I guess the python (PySpark code) for this join might be close to:

```
(users.join(events, on = [users.Id == events.Id], how = 'left')
      .join(events, on = [users.Cel == events.Id], how = 'left'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the following code

```
with_id = (users.join(events, on=users["Id"]==events["Id"], how='inner')
                .select(events["Id"], events["Name"],"Cel","Date","EventType"))

incorrect_id = (users.join(events, on=users["Id"]==events["Id"], how='leftanti')
                        .join(events, on=users["Cel"]==events["Id"])
                        .select(users["Id"], events["Name"],"Cel","Date","EventType"))


result = with_id.unionAll(incorrect_id)
```

The result

```
result.show()
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+
| Id|    Name|       Cel|      Date|EventType|
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+
|324|  Daniel|5511737379|2022-01-15| purchase|
|350|    Jack|3247623817|2022-01-16| purchase|
|380|Michelle|3247623322|2022-01-10|    claim|
+---+--------+----------+----------+---------+
```